# Como posso pegar verificar as diagonais de um caça palavras?

Tags: python, matriz

Já verifiquei alguns códigos aqui no site, mas não estou conseguindo. Estou criando um programa que recebe um caça palavra e mostra no terminal onde as palavras previamente declaradas estão.
Porém, estou com dificuldade agora para verificar na diagonal. Eu já tentei transformar cada linha diagonal em uma linha horizonta, e assim verificar se alguma palavra está presente lá.

Estou começando agora na programação, imagino que meu código esteja cheio de "erros", mas espero melhorar. Desde já obrigado.

Vou postar o código inteiro aqui:

```py
##### CAÇA PALAVRAS #####
print("Caça Palavras")

# Funções:
def definirCaçaPalavra():
  indexLinhas = int(input("Quantas linhas serão necessárias? "))
  for i in range(0, indexLinhas):
    linha = input("Digite a {}ª linha: ".format(i+1))
    linhaLista = list(linha)
    caçaPalavras.append(linhaLista)

def definirPalavras():
  indexPalavras = int(input("Quantas palavras serão procuradas? "))
  for i in range(0, indexPalavras):
    palavra = input("Digite a {}ª palavra: ".format(i+1))
    palavraLista = list(palavra)
    palavras.append(palavraLista)

def verificarHorizontal():
  for palavra in palavras:
    numeroLinha = 1
    for linha in caçaPalavras:
      linhaString = ''.join(linha)
      palavraString = ''.join(palavra)
      if palavraString in linhaString:
        print("Palavra {} encontrada na horizontal na {}ª linha".format(palavraString, numeroLinha))
      else:
        numeroLinha += 1

def verificarHorizontalInversa():
  for palavra in palavras:
    numeroLinha = 1
    for linha in caçaPalavras:
      linhaString = ''.join(linha)
      palavraString = ''.join(palavra)
      palavraInversaString = ''.join(reversed(palavra))
      if palavraInversaString in linhaString:
        print("Palavra {} ({}) encontrada na horizontal inversa na {}ª linha".format(palavraInversaString, palavraString, numeroLinha))
      else:
        numeroLinha += 1

def verificarVertical():
  tamanhoLinha = len(caçaPalavras[0])
  for i in range(0, tamanhoLinha):
    linhaHorizontalVertical = []
    for linha in caçaPalavras:
      linhaHorizontalVertical.append(linha[i])
    linhaHorizontalVerticalString = ''.join(linhaHorizontalVertical)
    for palavra in palavras:
      palavraString = ''.join(palavra)
      if palavraString in linhaHorizontalVerticalString:
        print("Palavra {} encontrada na {}ª vertical".format(palavraString, i+1))

def verificarVerticalInversa():
  tamanhoLinha = len(caçaPalavras[0])
  for i in range(0, tamanhoLinha):
    linhaHorizontalVertical = []
    for linha in caçaPalavras:
      linhaHorizontalVertical.append(linha[i])
    linhaHorizontalVerticalString = ''.join(linhaHorizontalVertical)
    for palavra in palavras:
      palavraInversaString = ''.join(reversed(palavra))
      palavraString = ''.join(palavra)
      if palavraInversaString in linhaHorizontalVerticalString:
        print("Palavra {} ({}) encontrada na {}ª vertical inversa".format(palavraInversaString, palavraString, i+1))
# Transformar linha diagonal em uma horizontal
```

Para cada letra, pegar da linha de baixo tamanho da linha +1.

```py
def verificarDiagonalBaixo():
  

# Variáveis:
caçaPalavras = []
palavras = []

# Principal
definirCaçaPalavra()
definirPalavras()
print("********************")
verificarHorizontal()
print("********************")
verificarHorizontalInversa()
print("********************")
verificarVertical()
print("********************")
verificarVerticalInversa()
print("********************")
verificarDiagonalBaixo()
```

Uma das coisas que eu tentei mas não funcionou foi:

```py
def verificarDiagonalBaixo():
  for linha in caçaPalavras:
    for letra in linha:
      contador = 1
      linhaHorizontalDiagonal = []
      linhaHorizontalDiagonal.append(letra)
      for linha in caçaPalavras:
        if contador < len(linha):
          linhaHorizontalDiagonal.append(linha[contador])
        contador += 1
      print(linhaHorizontalDiagonal)
```

Acho que talvez isso de uma idéia do que eu estou tentando fazer.

Isso aqui eu tentei também, e ele pegou a primeira diagonal. Talvez esteja no caminho certo:

```py
def verificarDiagonalBaixo():
  for linha in caçaPalavras:
    
      contador = 0
      linhaHorizontalDiagonal = []
      for linha in caçaPalavras:
        if contador < len(linha):
          linhaHorizontalDiagonal.append(linha[contador])
        contador += 1
  print(linhaHorizontalDiagonal)
```

Answer (score 0):

vamos supor que você queira olhar a diagonal de cima para baixo, da esquerda para a direita. Você não pode fazer um `for diagonal in ...` porque não tem onde procurar a diagonal, então a gente vai ter que começar olhando a primeira letra na linha 0 coluna 0 (0,0), a segunda na linha 1, coluna 1 (1,1), etc. Se a palavra tem N letras a gente termina em (N-1,N-1). Certo? Se a gente não achou a palavra, vamos começar a procurar agora com a primeira letra na linha 0 coluna 1 (0,1) e seguir até `(0,1)+(N-1,N-1)=(N-1,N)`. Existe um limite de que `(0,i)+(N-1,N-1)` não pode sair da margem da sua linha, então `N-1+i` tem que ser menor ou igual a `len(caçaPalavras[0])`, ou seja `i<len(caçaPalavras[0])-N`.

Vamos começar o código. Supondo que a sua palavra tenha 4 letras o código abaixo vai olhar as 4 primeiro letras da diagonal que começa em (0,0):

```
diagonal = [caçaPalavras[k][k] for k in range(4)]
```

Se a gente quiser fazer ela começar em `(0,i)` e usar uma palavra de tamanho N então vamos fazer:

```
N = len(palavra)
for i in range(len(caçaPalavras[0])-N):
    diagonal = [caçaPalavras[k][k+i] for k in range(N)]
```

para olhar as outras linhas você vai precisar de outro for e trocar o código acima por

```
N = len(palavra)
for j in range(len(caçapalavras)-N:
    for i in range(len(caçaPalavras[j])-N):
        diagonal = [caçaPalavras[k+j][k+i] for k in range(N)]
```

o que você quer comparar é se sua palavra é igual a `''.join(diagonal)`. Para as diagonais em outros sentidos você precisa trocar os sinais em `[k+i][k+j]` e acertar os limites do seu `for` mas se eu disser aqui como fazer estarei resolvendo o problema pra você. Acho que a partir daqui você já consegue quebrar a cabeça para resolver. Qualquer dúvida pergunte nos comentários.